# Корзина на Codeignither?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как выйти из такой ситуации.
Использую стандартную библиотеку cart и session.
Добавление товаров работает нормально, но при определенном кол-во, товар не добавляется. Почитал на формах понял, что в codeignithere можно хранить информации в сессиях не более 4 кб. Захожу в Куки копирую информацию, находящуюся в корзине:**

a%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%220f323658cd37a3db29652b7ef4b20d12%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%225.76.215.97%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A108%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.3%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F43.0.2357.81+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1432922413%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22cart_contents%22%3Ba%3A9%3A%7Bs%3A32%3A%2228dd2c7955ce926456240b2ff0100bde%22%3Ba%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22rowid%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%2228dd2c7955ce926456240b2ff0100bde%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2277%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22qty%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22price%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%225599%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A93%3A%22BIO+TRUE+ONE+DAY+%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B7%D1%8B%2C+30%D1%88%D1%82.%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22subtotal%22%3Bi%3A5599%3B%7Ds%3A32%3A%223295c76acbf4caaed33c36b1b5fc2cb1%22%3Ba%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22rowid%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%223295c76acbf4caaed33c36b1b5fc2cb1%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2266%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22qty%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22price%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%226600%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A91%3A%22BIOCLEAR+1+DAY+%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B7%D1%8B%2C+30%D1%88%D1%82.%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22subtotal%22%3Bi%3A6600%3B%7Ds%3A32%3A%2272b32a1f754ba1c09b3695e0cb6cde7f%22%3Ba%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22rowid%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%2272b32a1f754ba1c09b3695e0cb6cde7f%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2257%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22qty%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22price%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%229900%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A106%3A%22CLARITI+1DAY+%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B7%D1%8B++%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C+30%D1%88%D1%82%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22subtotal%22%3Bi%3A9900%3B%7Ds%3A32%3A%226c8349cc7260ae62e3b1396831a8398f%22%3Ba%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22rowid%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%226c8349cc7260ae62e3b1396831a8398f%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2245%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22qty%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22price%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%226399%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A85%3A%22BIOMEDICS+1+DAY+EXTRA+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B7%D1%8B+%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%2C+30%D1%88%D1%82.%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22subtotal%22%3Bi%3A6399%3B%7Ds%3A32%3A%226f4922f45568161a8cdf4ad2299f6d23%22%3Ba%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22rowid%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%226f4922f45568161a8cdf4ad2299f6d23%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2218%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22qty%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22price%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%224999%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A33%3A%22DAILIES+AquaComfort+Plus+30+%D1%88%D1%82.%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22subtotal%22%3Bi%3A4999%3B%7Ds%3A32%3A%2270efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb%22%3Ba%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22rowid%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%2270efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2217%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22qty%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22price%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%227399%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A28%3A%221-Day+ACUVUE+TruEye+30+%D1%88%D1%82.%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22subtotal%22%3Bi%3A7399%3B%7Ds%3A32%3A%229bf31c7ff062936a96d3c8bd1f8f2ff3%22%3Ba%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22rowid%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%229bf31c7ff062936a96d3c8bd1f8f2ff3%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2215%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22qty%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22price%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%226399%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A27%3A%221-Day+Acuvue+Moist+30+%D1%88%D1%82.%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22subtotal%22%3Bi%3A6399%3B%7Ds%3A11%3A%22total_items%22%3Bi%3A7%3Bs%3A10%3A%22cart_total%22%3Bi%3A47295%3B%7D%7Dd73f5e37a201f5754b4b6acd07bd590a

**получается 4 кб. Скажите пожалуйста как обойти это ограничение или как вы выходили из этой ситуации.?**

Comment: Храните в сессии или БД.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли! Зачтите как правильный ответ!